# What is the correct pattern for loading multiple views?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to load 3 views when a page is loaded.

Currently I do it like this:

```
/**
 * BVComposite
 */

    var BVComposite = Backbone.View.extend({
        Name: 'BVComposite',
        render: function (token) {
            this.BVFave = new BVFave({  el: $A.el('#mm'),
                collection: new BCFave([], {data: {h_token: token, model: "FavoriteReader"}})
            });
            this.BVFeed = new BVFeed({el: $A.el('#at_view'),
                collection: new BCFeed([], {data: {h_token: token, model: "FeedReader"}})
            });
            this.BVAccount = new BVAccount({ model: new BMAccount([],
                {data: {h_token: token, model: "AccountReader"}})
            });
        }
    });
```

Then I call it like this ( on page load )

```
var composite_view = $A.Class.add(new BVComposite());
composite_view.render(token);
```

Is there a better way to do this.  That is, is there a design pattern to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd put all that code into an `initialize` function, and then let the composite view call the children's `render`.

```
var BVComposite = Backbone.View.extend({
        Name: 'BVComposite',
        initialize:function(){
            this.BVFave = new BVFave({  el: $A.el('#mm'),
                collection: new BCFave([], {data: {h_token: token, model: "FavoriteReader"}})
            });
            this.BVFeed = new BVFeed({el: $A.el('#at_view'),
                collection: new BCFeed([], {data: {h_token: token, model: "FeedReader"}})
            });
            this.BVAccount = new BVAccount({ model: new BMAccount([],
                {data: {h_token: token, model: "AccountReader"}})
            });
        },
        render: function (token) {
            this.BVFave.render();
            this.BVFeed.render();
            this.BVAccount.render();
        }
    });
```

Try to only put code related to DOM manipulation in your render function. In your initialize function, i would put any logic needed to setup the View, stuff like assigning a `model` or `collection`, handling an `options` parameter, etc. This keeps your intent clear and easier to understand.

Comment: By the looks of his codes, those views are self rendering. There is no need to initialize and render them separately, so it's fine to have it in render..